# how to fetch data which start with from MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have to fetch data from MySQL which is starts with user-entered data. I have tried using LIKE but it's not working, I have given the code below which I have tried to get results.
event.booksName which is user-entered data.

```
  connection.query("select * from books where booksName like "+event.booksName% + " user_id like ? " , [event.user_id], (err,res ,fields) =>{
   console.log("resres",res)
        callback(null, {
            status :
            message :
            data : res
        });
    })
```

Comment: try replacing like this '"+event.booksName + "%'. notice '

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 connection.query(`select * from books where booksName like '${event.booksName}%' user_id like ? ` , [event.user_id], (err,res ,fields) =>{
   console.log("resres",res)
        callback(null, {
            status :
            message :
            data : res
        });
    })
```